# Why do the Heat Map (QGIS) and Kernel density estimation (SAGA) tools provide different results?

Tags: qgis, kernel-density

The Heat Map tool (QGIS) and the Kernel Density Estimation tool (SAGA) provide different results for the same data as shown below.
Why is this happening?
Is one of them more conceptually correct?

**Heatmap - QGIS**
Radius: 100 m
 - Weight from field: count
 - Output raster size: 1 m
 - Kernel shape: quartic
 - Output value scaling: scaled
 - Fit: I have understood how to nodes
[image]

**Kernel - SAGA**
Radius: 100 m
 - Weight from field: count
 - Output raster size: 1 m
 - Fit: nodes
 - Kernel shape: quartic kernel
 - Out put value scaling: I have understood how to scaled
[image]

The difference between the Heatmap tool results (QGIS) and the results of the Kernel D.E. (SAGA) tool can be seen below.
[image]

Comment: It's possible the two algorithms handle duplicate geometries differently - do you have any point(s) with the exact same coordinate? Try subtracting one raster from the other, it might give clues as to where they vary?

Comment: Yes, each point has the same coordinates in both attempts (the same point layer was used).
The difference between the results of the Heatmap tool (QGIS) and the results of the Kernel D.E (SAGA) tool was increased above. @StevenKay

Comment: There seem to be the same distribution but with different value, maybe the two tool return the same result but with a different indicator

Comment: Thank you for posting the difference raster! Sorry, I probably didn't word my comment clearly :-) I meant, are there any 2 (or more) features in your layer that have the same coordinate. You can find these using a "point displacement" style.  If all points sit on their own, they're unique. If you see anything that looks like 'atoms' (several points on a circle) you have duplicates.

Comment: @Sergio visually, aren't they all the same? I feel any 'heat map' is not about the 'units' so much as it is about the visualization of the change from high to low. Using any density-type tool usually tries to achieve a 'units per square area' as in to go into further analysis. The above rasters *look* all the same - is it the units that are causing the concern?

Comment: @StevenKay No, we do not have duplicate points.

Comment: @DPSSpatial Qualitatively the results are actually very similar. But quantitatively, the results from the Heatmap (QGIS) are up to 7 times higher than the results obtained by Kernel D. E. (SAGA). In this particular study the value of density is important and I would like to know what value I should take to make decisions.

Comment: @Sergio If you are doing true density analysis, I would suggest getting into the GRASS tools in order to get the most accurate results. Heatmap is not a 'density' tool, it's just a visualization tool and the output values never mean much in our attempts at using it.

Comment: @J.R Both results are computed according to an area with radius of 100 m and distributed according to a matrix with resolution of 1 m x 1 m, considering quartic kernel shape.

Comment: @DPSSpatial Thank you. I already used the GRASS GIS Kernel tool and I got intermediate results, compared to the results already shown. I think I'm going to adopt the GRASS Kernel tool values.